# What is the meaning of "for" in the context below?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Everyone laughed when Albert went to work in his baggy pants. Everyone but Albert. He punched one of his workmates in the eye. 
>   And that is when the joke really fell flat. **For** the incident led to a strike which crippled production at carpet factory.

I think here "for" means "because of", but I doubt it because the whole sentence is unclear to me.

I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: Yes, it does mean "because". A strike which crippled production at a carpet factory occurred _because_ Albert punched one of his workmates in the eye.

Comment: What is the source? It would be helpful to know when and where this was written.

Answer (score 1):

You use a good dictionary to find out the meaning of a word.

> for preposition (BECAUSE OF) ​ A2 because of or as a result of
>   something:
>
> I'm feeling all the better for my holiday. "How are you?" "Fine, and
>   all the better for seeing you!" She did 15 years in prison for murder.
>   I don't eat meat for various reasons. I couldn't see for the tears in
>   my eyes. The things you do for love! He's widely disliked in the
>   company for his arrogance. She couldn't talk for coughing (= she was
>   coughing too much to talk). Scotland is famous for its spectacular
>   countryside. He's best remembered for his novels. I didn't say
>   anything for fear of (= because I was frightened of) offending him.

[For (Cambridge Dictionaries)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)

Answer (score 1):

"For" indeed means "because of," or "due to." It's not commonly used these days, outside of poetry and music. See the third definition here: [for preposition (BECAUSE OF)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for).

There's a famous poem which starts:

> *For the want of a nail, the shoe was lost*

Which means "because a nail was missing, the [horse]shoe was lost."